# More arguments are passed than are actually used in the format string

Tags: java, string, formatting, findbugs

FindBugs gives me a '*More arguments are passed than are actually used in the format string*' message on the following code:

```
String.format("00", bd.getHour())
```

`bd.getHour()` returns an `int`.

Can someone clarify this? My obective is to make sure that 1 digit ints are preceded by a 0 (1 ->01, 13->13...).

What is the right way to achieve this without getting a FindBugs message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) follows the rules of [format string](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), so use:

```
String.format("%02d", bd.getHour());
```

Because your line, will just print `00` and ignore the added parameter.